# Is there any fuction of R that given a dataframe with n numerical variables, tell you for each variable, in what rank from 1 to n is each row?

Tags: r, dataframe

Imagine we have a data frame that includes 3 numerical variables, for example the probability of having a certain illness after a test

```
             Diabetes     Lyme     Anaemia
                                    
Anthony      0.040457  0.326594     0.14    
Mary         0.279323  0.877446     0.37
Paul         0.328068  0.837669     0.48
Markus       0.107959  0.678297     0.12
Jeremy       0.131555  0.418380     0.123
Sarah        0.999961  0.619517     0.4
Eve          0.129270  0.024533     0.8
Whitney      0.441010  0.741781     0.9
```

I want to 3 aditional variables that tells you what rank is each illness compared to the other ones, being 1 the max and 3 the minimum. For example:

```
             Diabetes     Lyme     Anaemia     Diabetes_rank   Lyme_Rank   Anaemia_Rank
                                    
Anthony      0.040457  0.326594     0.14        3                 1             2
Mary         0.279323  0.877446     0.37        3                 1             2
Paul         0.328068  0.837669     0.048       2                 1             3
Markus       0.910795  0.678297     0.12        1                 2             3
Jeremy       0.13155   0.418380     0.883       3                 2             1
Sarah        0.999961  0.619517     0.4
Eve          0.129270  0.024533     0.8
Whitney      0.441010  0.741781     0.9
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll use your second data, since the two are different.

```r
quux <- structure(list(Diabetes = c(0.040457, 0.279323, 0.328068, 0.910795, 0.13155, 0.999961, 0.12927, 0.44101), Lyme = c(0.326594, 0.877446, 0.837669, 0.678297, 0.41838, 0.619517, 0.024533, 0.741781), Anaemia = c(0.14, 0.37, 0.048, 0.12, 0.883, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Anthony", "Mary", "Paul", "Markus", "Jeremy", "Sarah", "Eve", "Whitney"))
```

## base R

```r
quux <- cbind(quux, setNames(data.frame(t(apply(quux, 1, \(z) rank(-z)))), paste0(names(quux), "_rank")))
quux
#         Diabetes     Lyme Anaemia Diabetes_rank Lyme_rank Anaemia_rank
# Anthony 0.040457 0.326594   0.140             3         1            2
# Mary    0.279323 0.877446   0.370             3         1            2
# Paul    0.328068 0.837669   0.048             2         1            3
# Markus  0.910795 0.678297   0.120             1         2            3
# Jeremy  0.131550 0.418380   0.883             3         2            1
# Sarah   0.999961 0.619517   0.400             1         2            3
# Eve     0.129270 0.024533   0.800             2         3            1
# Whitney 0.441010 0.741781   0.900             3         2            1
```

- `apply(quux, 1, ..)` works on each *row* (`1`) of `quux`, and the anonymous function is passed a vector at a time (e.g., first call gets `c(0.040457, 0.326594, 0.14)`).
- we use `rank(-z)` internally since you want the minimum to be `3`
- `t(..)` because `apply` when row-wise returns what appears to be a transposed matrix
- `setNames(..)` to append `_rank` to each name
- `cbind` to combine it column-wise with `quux`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `matrixStats::rowRanks`.

```
matrixStats::rowRanks(as.matrix(-quux))
#         Diabetes Lyme Anaemia
# Anthony        3    1       2
# Mary           3    1       2
# Paul           2    1       3
# Markus         1    2       3
# Jeremy         3    2       1
# Sarah          1    2       3
# Eve            2    3       1
# Whitney        3    2       1
```

[@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76711744/6574038) already shows the `cbind` trick.

---

*Data:*

```
quux <- structure(list(Diabetes = c(0.040457, 0.279323, 0.328068, 0.910795, 
0.13155, 0.999961, 0.12927, 0.44101), Lyme = c(0.326594, 0.877446, 
0.837669, 0.678297, 0.41838, 0.619517, 0.024533, 0.741781), Anaemia = c(0.14, 
0.37, 0.048, 0.12, 0.883, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Anthony", 
"Mary", "Paul", "Markus", "Jeremy", "Sarah", "Eve", "Whitney"
))
```